# My computer has no admin user

Tags: macos, security, administrator, single-user

In system preferences, under users, standard is written under my name and there is no admin.

When i try to change preferences it asks for admin name and password to unlock it but my login password doesn't work as I'm not an admin.

Answer (score 4):

Boot into single user mode.

Delete the file `/var/db/.AppleSetupDone` and then `type exit` and press return

At that point, the system will boot back to the normal setup process (keeping your old users intact) You will be guided through the steps to create a new admin user so pick a short name that doesn't exist on the Mac and you can then re-grant your normal user admin rights if you wish.

Comment: Great answer just for fun run a backup first -- just out of paranoia :)

Answer (score 0):

One could also try:

`dseditgroup -o edit -a shortnamehere -t user admin`

But you would likely have to boot into single user mode as mentioned before because I'm pretty sure you can't do it without being root first.

Comment: Does `dseditgroup` even work in single user mode these days?