# Can't Log In, Removed applesetupdone to try as new admin but need it back

Tags: login, startup, login-screen

So, it's a multilayered problem.

My bluetooth keyboard (logicool - no USB) stopped working or connecting. I tried disconnecting/connecting and then decided to just reset my Macbook just in case. When back on the log-in screen, I remembered why I had the bluetooth keyboard (which isn't working/has been disconnected): some keys don't work. The same keys I need for the password and for my appleID/pass.

So, i tried following this article's advice 
https://www.lifewire.com/create-new-admin-account-for-login-issues-2259976

and again came across the issue of needing to type things with keys that don't work. So, I'd like to reverse what I did with the lifewire article - so that it boots normally again, and not asking me to setup an admin account.

So my question is about how do I reverse that? Any tips? And any way to launch the on-screen keyboard on the login screen?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYWRG.jpg Can you get to this screen ? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac/164332#164332 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202143/i-included-emoji-in-my-password-and-now-i-cant-log-in-to-my-account-on-yosemite

Comment: Get a new keyboard. They are a dime a dozen.  Windows key is the command key. Just create a new admin account then delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From single-user mode (boot with cmd-s on T1 or earlier), run the following to mount the disk read-write, create the AppleSetupDone file with the correct permissions, then reboot.

```
/sbin/mount -uw /
touch /var/db/.AppleSetupDone
chmod 400 /var/db/.AppleSetupDone
reboot
```

With T2, single-user mode is accessed with [cmd-R + Terminal](https://support.apple.com/HT201573), so you'll need to mount the internal disk at `/Volumes/diskname` and prefix the touch/chmod commands with the path to your disk.